# C# Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework

EF is making some properties non nullable by default in the database, is there some way to over ride this for certain properties ? I tried searching for a data annotation but found nothing.

I am using code first the properties are an int and a datetime

Comment: are you using code first? what is the type of the property?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941472/entity-framework-code-first-default-values-on-non-nullable-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using code-first. You are probably getting non-nullable for types that are indeed non-nullable (value types), like int, bool, etc. You need to use the nullable version of these in order to do this:

```
int? MyColumnThatIsNullable
```

and **NOT** this

```
int MyColumnThatIsNOTNullable
```

Think about how the code would work and this will make sense to you. If a field is an int and a null is attempted to be passed into the code, then you will either have some sort of error, or a magic (default) value. This will not properly represent the value in the database. So, if you use the nullable version, then the null in the database can be represented for what it truly is, a null.

Comment: Hah! now that you mention it that makes perfect sense, and I cant figure out how I missed it. Thanks

Comment: @Roge No problem, I added an explanation below my original answer (although you said you got it :)). As usual accepted answers (once the 15 min grace period is up) and upvotes are appreciated :)